# How to do a calculation by evaluating several conditions?

Tags: excel, ms-access

I have this table in access called invoices.

It has a field that performs calculations based on two fields. that is field_price*field_Quantity. Now I added two new columns containing the unit of measure for field_weight and field_quantity named field_priceUnit and field_quantityUnit.

Now instead of just taking the multiplication to perform the calculation, I want it to see if the units of measures match, it doesn't match then it should do a convertion of the field_quantity into the unit of measure of field_priceUnit.

example:

Row1:
ID:1|Field_Quantity:23|field_quantityUnit:LB|Field_weight:256|field_priceunit:KG|field_price:24| Calculated_Column:

the calculated_column should do the calculation this way.
1. if field_quantityunit=LB and field_priceunit=LB then field_quantity*field_price

else

if field_quantityUnit=LB and field_priceUnit=KG
THEN ((field_quantity/0.453592)*field_price)             <<

Please help me.

I have to do this for multiple conditions.
Field_priceunit may have values as LB,KG, and MT
Field_quantityUnit may have field as LB,KG, and MT

if both units don't match, then I want to do the conversion and calculate based on the new convetion as seen in the example.

Thank you

Comment: `iif(and(field_quantityunit='LB', field_priceunit='LB'), field_quantity*field_price, (field_quantity/0.453592)*field_price)` This is going to get really really ugly though as you add more units. Consider a table that has `units | conversion_amount` to convert all of your units into a common unit (whatever you like). Then you can join this table in to each unit and do your math on `conversion_amount`. Nice and scalable.

Comment: Thank you for the help and advice, but how do I do the advice you are recommending. Sorry, its a little confusing to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following formula should get you running if your units are only `lb` and `kg` and you only have to check one direction:

```
iif(and(field_quantityunit='LB', field_priceunit='LB'), field_quantity*field_price, (field_quantity/0.453592)*field_price)
```

This doesn't scale well though as you may have to convert field_price or you may add other units. This `iif` formula will grow WAY out of hand quickly.

Instead create a new table called `unit_conversion` or whatever you like:

```
unit | conversion
lb   | .453592
kg   | 1
g    | 1000
mg   | 1000000
```

Now in your query join:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN unit_conversion as qty_conversion
    ON field_quantityunit = qty_conversion.unit
LEFT OUTER JOIN unit_conversion as price_conversion
    On field_priceUnit = price_conversion.unit
```

Up in your SELECT portion of the query you can now just do:

```
 (field_quantity * qty_conversion.conversion) * (field_price * price_conversion.conversion)
```

And you don't have to worry what the units are. They will all convert over to a kilogram and get multiplied.

You could convert everything over to a pound or really any unit of weight here if you want but the nice thing is, you only need to add new units to your conversion table to handle them in any sql that you write this way so it's very scalable.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have a question. Is there a way I can call this query into a column inside a table. That is store the calculation in a table.

Comment: If you want to store them on the same table, then maybe create two new columns and then run an UPDATE statement to fill them. I wouldn't convert them and store that conversion in the existing fields only because I really hate overwriting original data. But.. it's your database so do as you like. 

If this were mine, I would probably just write a nice query to take care of this join and logic and then use the query when accessing the data having it all stitched together only when I needed it.